# More detailed error from runbuf function in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I try to build some kind of X++ script executor and therefore play around with the runbuf function.
It works as long as the X++ code I pass in is valid, but when I pass invalid code then it just throws an error that it is not able to compile the code but no further details.
For example when I try the following code

```
runbuf('void dynAdd(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }');
```

it fails with the error

> Unable to compile "void dynAdd(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + rhs;
>   }".

Is there a way to get more information about the error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [XppCompiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xppcompiler.aspx) for that like so

```
static void DynamicXppTest(Args _args)
{
    str         dynamicXpp;
    int         result;
    XppCompiler xppCompiler;
    ;

    dynamicXpp = 'void dynAdd(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }';

    // previous runbuf - style
    // 
    // result = runbuf(dynamicXpp, 3, 4);
    // info(strfmt("result = %1", result));

    xppCompiler = new XppCompiler();
    if (xppCompiler.compile(dynamicXpp))
    {
        result = xppCompiler.execute(3, 4);
        info(strfmt("result = %1", result));
    }
    else
    {
        error(xppCompiler.errorText());
    }
}
```

which will result in the below error in the infolog

> *** Error: 82, The operand is not compatible with the type of the function.